# sending selected listbox items to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox

My scenario is here 
      OK i have a multi-select listbox, what i want is when we select multiple records 
      and  press button, i should i have selected items list in calling method of 
      controller. my code is below

**csthml code :**

```
@{
 Layout = "";
}
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using System.Web;
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@model Nop.Plugin.Import.Product.Models.ImportProductModel
<div>
<div class="section-header">
    <div class="options">            
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportSelected",  "ImportProduct"))
    {
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    }
    </div>
 </div>

 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ListBox("Items", Model.nopCommerceCategories);
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ListBox("Items", Model.ClockCategories);
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveMapping", "ImportProduct"))
                {
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                }
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>        
 </div>
```

**Model :**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Import.Product.Models
{
    public class ImportProductModel
    {        
        public List<SelectListItem> nopCommerceCategories { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> ClockCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful : the first parameter for the listbox is the name that you want to send to your controller! You should thus use such code :

```
@Html.ListBox("nopCommerceCategories", Model.nopCommerceCategories);
@* or this code :
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.nopCommerceCategories);
*@
```

And then when you call your controller with the following signature :

```
 public ActionResult SaveMapping(ImportProductModel ipm) {
     // here you have access to ipm.nopCommerceCategories
 }
```

Moreover you have to encapsulate all your code with the data that you want to get in one form!
And if you want to submit on more than one action, add a javascript code in order to retrieve the correct action to submit your data...

Answer (score 0):

your forms have just a submit button inside, you should put your listboxes inside a form, and when the form will be submited, the value of the listbox and everything else that is inside the form will be sent to the action that the form points to